# symfony2 Get exact content from BuzzBundle response

Tags: php, symfony, httpresponse, buzz

How can I get exact content from [BuzzBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioBuzzBundle) without header or other information

currently I am using ,

```
 $buzz = $this->container->get('buzz');
 $response = $buzz->get('http://api.ipify.org?format=json');
 echo $response;
```

and output is,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Cowboy Connection: close Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Content-Type: text/plain Date: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 14:51:40 GMT Content-Length: 14 Via: 1.1 vegur {"ip":"54.254.210.209"}
```

here only `{"ip":"111.20.67.90"}` is desired response.

or any other way to do so, with different bundle, or i have to use curl directly in PHP code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, `BuzzBundle` is just a small configuration file that [injects the `Buzz` library into Symfony](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz).

When you use the `get()` method of `Browser`, it returns an instance of `call()` with [a return value of `MessageInterface`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Browser.php#L67)... so [let's examine that file](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Message/MessageInterface.php):

```
/**
 * Returns the message document.
 *
 * @return string The message
 */
public function __toString();
```

This is just the equivalent of a header file if you're familiar with `C++`, but it's clear that the `__toString()` file returns the full message, including headers. So if we look through the rest of that file, we find that [there's another function that gets what you want](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Message/MessageInterface.php#L57):

```
/**
 * Returns the content of the message.
 *
 * @return string The message content
 */
public function getContent();
```

So if you treat the `MessageInterface` as an object instead of trying to access it like a string (which gives you its default of `__toString()`), this is the code you would use:

```
$buzz = $this->container->get('buzz');
$response = $buzz->get('http://api.ipify.org?format=json');
echo $response->getContent(); // output: {"ip":"54.254.210.209"}
```